# How to properly pass argument values to sql query? java, netbeans

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, oracle11g

I have problem with sql query statement. How to pass argument values to sql query properly? When I click button it shows "INVALID ALTER COMMAND". Old_table_name, New_table_name are text fields

```
public void Change_table_name(String old_name, String new_name){
    try{
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Alter table"+old_name.trim()+"Rename to"+new_name.trim());
        Table_Database.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

private void Change_table_nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    String old_name = Old_table_name.getText().toString();
    String new_name = New_table_name.getText().toString();
    Change_table_name(old_name, new_name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your give some space in query.. like that..

```
"Alter table "+old_name.trim()+" Rename to "+new_name.trim());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It changed the table name but Now when I run the program again it says table or view does not exist. Error code:942. and it is calling old table name instead new one. However, in database viewer the table name is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your method, change that to the below method

```
    public void Change_table_name(String old_name, String new_name){
try{
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Alter table "+old_name.trim()+" Rename to "+new_name.trim());
    Table_Database.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
}
```

Try this by giving space if didn't work then give single quotes,

```
public void Change_table_name(String old_name, String new_name){
try{
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Alter table '"+old_name.trim()+"' Rename to '"+new_name.trim()+"'");
    Table_Database.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! :) After inserting single quotes it is saying: Invalid table name. What should I do?

Comment: I got message: Cannot set a null TableModel. However table name changes. What error is this? What does it mean?

Comment: This line **ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Alter table "+old_name.trim()+" Rename to "+new_name.trim());** doesn't return any result set so your result set value will be null & you are assigning that **res** object to TableModel, that's why you get this error.

Comment: Try by commenting this line **Table_Database.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));** and use this statement **stmt.executeQuery("Alter table "+old_name.trim()+" Rename to "+new_name.trim());** without assigning to **res**

Comment: I got what you mean. But what should I do with result set in order to update(change) my table name. TableModel i use to display data from table in jtable

Comment: I can help you till this because I didn't work much with swing, try to google search about this issue you got here.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery(). As Ajeessh has pointed out, the "Alter table..." does not return any result set.